# Javascript not being run when a linked script has defer in the script tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a website being built using PHP, javascript HTML CSS and the likes. I am using the Laravel PHP framework. I have an issue with some javascript not running on the page. The main things happening on the website with javascript is form validation, datatables and my own javascript relating to a couple of forms where it will provide the user with suggestions for that text box as they type if they start typing something which is in an array in the javascipt. There is a linked script tag used by Laravel for 'app.js' and this tag has 'defer' inside it. All JS is working apart from my own JS script around the form suggestions. If I remove the word 'defer' from the 'app.js' script tag, my own code works and suggests things to the users, but datatables etc stops working. Could someone please help me? I need all code running (even if that means changing codes somehow). I have pasted the codes below.

```js
<script>
        var brands = ["HP", "Dell", "Test"];
        function autocomplete(inp, arr) {
            /*the autocomplete function takes two arguments,
            the text field element and an array of possible autocompleted values:*/
            var currentFocus;
            /*execute a function when someone writes in the text field:*/
            inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
                var a, b, i, val = this.value;
                /*close any already open lists of autocompleted values*/
                closeAllLists();
                if (!val) { return false;}
                currentFocus = -1;
                /*create a DIV element that will contain the items (values):*/
                a = document.createElement("DIV");
                a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
                a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");
                /*append the DIV element as a child of the autocomplete container:*/
                this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
                /*for each item in the array...*/
                for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
                    if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
                    /*create a DIV element for each matching element:*/
                    b = document.createElement("DIV");
                    /*make the matching letters bold:*/
                    b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
                    b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
                    /*insert a input field that will hold the current array item's value:*/
                    b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
                    /*execute a function when someone clicks on the item value (DIV element):*/
                        b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                        /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
                        inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                        /*close the list of autocompleted values,
                        (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
                        closeAllLists();
                    });
                    a.appendChild(b);
                    }
                }
            });
            /*execute a function presses a key on the keyboard:*/
            inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
                var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
                if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
                if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                    /*If the arrow DOWN key is pressed,
                    increase the currentFocus variable:*/
                    currentFocus++;
                    /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
                    addActive(x);
                } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
                    /*If the arrow UP key is pressed,
                    decrease the currentFocus variable:*/
                    currentFocus--;
                    /*and and make the current item more visible:*/
                    addActive(x);
                } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    /*If the ENTER key is pressed, prevent the form from being submitted,*/
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if (currentFocus > -1) {
                    /*and simulate a click on the "active" item:*/
                    if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
                    }
                }
            });
            function addActive(x) {
                /*a function to classify an item as "active":*/
                if (!x) return false;
                /*start by removing the "active" class on all items:*/
                removeActive(x);
                if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
                if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
                /*add class "autocomplete-active":*/
                x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
            }
            function removeActive(x) {
                /*a function to remove the "active" class from all autocomplete items:*/
                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
                }
            }
            function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
                /*close all autocomplete lists in the document,
                except the one passed as an argument:*/
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
                x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
                }
            }
            }
            /*execute a function when someone clicks in the document:*/
            document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                closeAllLists(e.target);
            });
        }
        autocomplete(document.getElementById("brand"), brands);
</script>
```

```html
<!-- A text field from the form -->
<div class="form-group row autocomplete">
    <label for="brand" class="text text-info">Brand:</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="brand" name="brand" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please enter a brand.
    </div>
</div>
<!-- End of text field from the form -->
    
<!-- Scripts Tags-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/d00af4d668.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs4/dt-1.10.22/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.4/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.4/js/buttons.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.4/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.4/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.6.4/js/buttons.colVis.min.js"></script>
<!-- ENd Of Scripts Tags -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did you put your javascript? Your javascript should be put in your app/resources/js folder.  And it should be accessed like this:

`<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}?q={{ time() }}" defer></script>`

Comment: Hi - Sorry, I have amended my post as I realise I used the code displayed to the user, not the source code, so that script tag was slightly different, but it does actually match yours other than I don't have 'q={{ time() }}' - do I need this? The code is stored in the location you mentioned. The custom script above is only on the view page where the form is.

Comment: It has now been fixed! Ordering the scripts differently and keeping the 'defer' removed has fixed the problem! The datatables scripts needed to run before 'app.js' and the custom code I have had to run after the 'app.js' had been run. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: @NathanGoldsmith Glad you got it working. And keeping the scripts in the correct order definitely helps.